# Legal protection for the title "university" in California

Tags: accreditation, law

Some non-academic organizations in United States use "university" as part of their name without official accreditation, and I've been struggling to figure out to what extent the university title is protected in the U.S. I'm particularly interested in California law.

In New York State, [EDN § 224](https://codes.findlaw.com/ny/education-law/edn-sect-224.html) prohibits non-accredited organizations from referring to themselves as a "university," but I haven't been able to find similar federal or California regulation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Law SE.

Comment: @user3209815 that's not a valid close reason. If it is on-topic here, it stays, even if it wouls be *more* on-topic elsewhere. Some animals are more equal than other animals, Oceania has always been at war with Eastasia.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccredited_institutions_of_higher_education#United_States_of_America) there are no national level protections in the USA, and California "permits anyone to claim to operate a college and issue degrees with essentially no oversight". Given that they're so lax in that respect, I'd speculate that they're unlikely to have protections for those terms.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike some other countries, there is no strong federal regulation that controls the titles like "University" and "College".  A few states have state level regulations, but federally there isn't any.

By the looking at the number of degree factories in California, I doubt that state of California has strong control over the title as well.

Some people became professors in regular four year colleges outside of the states with PhD's from these colleges without attending the class once or even visiting the campus - well, there isn't any campus to visit anyway.

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but any university that lets someone become a professor based on a false degree, deserves said applicant.

Comment: Yes, it is really pathetic.  Even in the states, it is a real problem.  There should be stronger regulations.  It really sickens me.